# HashMap in Tree structure in Java

Tags: java, tree, hashmap, containers, treemap

I am looking for a container that would basically work like `HashMap` where I could put and get any of the entries in O(1) time. I also want to be able to iterate through but I want the order to be sorted by values. So neither `TreeMap` nor `LinkedHashMap` would work for me. I found the example below:

```
SortedSet<Map.Entry<String, Double>> sortedSet = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<String, Double>>(
        new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Double>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Double> e1,
                    Map.Entry<String, Double> e2) {
                return e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
            }});
```

The problem is `SortedSet` doesn't have any get method to get entries.
I will be using this collection in a place where I will be adding entries but in case of already existing entry, the value(double) will be updated and then sorted again by using the comparator(which compares values as mentioned above). What can I use for my needs?

Comment: The question contradicts itself.  At one point you say that you want to iterate in key order.  In another, you want to iterate in value order.

Comment: @StephenC sorry, I did not mean to confuse you. The ordering should be done based on value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such data structure in the Java class libraries.

But you could create one that is a wrapper for a private HashMap and a private TreeMap with the same set of key/value pairs.

This gives a data structure that has `get` complexity of `O(1)` like a regular `HashMap` (but not `put` or other update operations), and a key Set and entry Set which can be iterated in key order ... as requested in the original version of this Question.

---

Here is a start for you:

```
public class HybridMap<K,V> implements Map<K,V> {
    private HashMap<K,V> hashmap = ...
    private TreeMap<K,V> treemap = ...

    @Override V get(K key) {
        return hashmap.get(key);
    }

    @Override void (K key, V value) {
        hashmap.put(key, value);
        treemap.put(key, value);
    }

    // etcetera
}
```

Obviously, I've only implemented some of the (easy) methods.

---

If you want to be able to iterate the entries in value order (rather than key order), once again there is no such data structure in the Java class libraries.

In this case, wrapping a `HashMap` and `TreeMap` is going to be very complicated if you need the resulting `Map` to conform fully to the API contract.

So I suggest that you just use a HashMap and TreeSet of the key/value pairs ... and manually keep them in step.

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: I updated my question just to avoid any misunderstanding. AFAIK, this wouldn't work because we are using `HashMap` to do O(1) lookup but `TreeMap` doesn't support usage of Comparator by values. So iteration would fail in this case.

Comment: @SarpKaya - The Question says *"I also want to be able to iterate through but I want the order to be sorted by the value **of keys**."*

Comment: I meant value of keys as in values that corresponds to keys.